# ModX Evo: TinyMCE wont insert image path into image URL in selector

Tags: tinymce, modx, modx-evolution

This is occuring on ModX Evo 1.0.15.

When I try to select an image (or file) using TinyMCEs image selector I can upload and browse for the image but when I select it to place within my text nothing happens - the image path area remains blank.

Heres a video demonstrating what happens: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSgTsyj9B6k&feature=youtu.be&hd=1

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Weird, never had that problem.
Did you try update / reinstall of Evo? (or only tinymce and kcfinder)
Are config paths correct?

[image: screendump1]
[image: screendump2]

Answer (score 0):

Try testing in Firefox, It's possible it's related to Chrome. If it doesn't work in Firefox, Reinstall the plugin.

Clear your cache and try selecting the image.

For a temporary solution if this doesn't work, just type in the image name into the box 'images/imagename.jpg' (minus quotes)

Good Luck